# Storing mail and contacts in NSF file in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

We have created a c# code which will migrate mails as well as contacts in nsf. Until now we were creating two different nsf files for mail and contact, as both contain different templates, but is it possible that mail as well as contact can be stored in same nsf file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on the individual user's mailbox that allows them to store contacts to be accessed by iNotes. From the Notes Client, go to File > Preferences.  Under the Contacts tab there is a check box for '**Enable Synchronize Contacts** on the Replication and Sync Tab'.

Unlike setting up Roaming for a user, these contacts appear to be stored within the users mail file on our server, because there is no trace of a second .nsf on server, but the contacts are accessible through iNotes. I am not sure within the template of the mailfile where the contacts exist, but they must be there.

May not have answered your question completely, but I hope it leads you down the correct path.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
but i need to create a nsf at a offline mode that too programatically.